# How to Retrieve data within nested select statement?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

My requirement is, there are two tables one is Stock table another one is packaging table. The normalization is 1:M that means 1 stock id can pack into many packages. In the packaging table there are two stockIDs one is FromStockID and another one is StockID. From both stock ids I wanted to retrieve appropriate stockID wise item code.

The data structure is:

[image]

I have tried using inner join and got an error.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?  You're on the right track with `INNER JOIN`.  I think I speak for most of us when i say that we want you to learn something, not just give you the code.

Comment: Please post the table definitions and sample data in a consumable way. You're just a few clicks away from a good question. Read here how to create it http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This query is my solution:

```
SELECT Packaging_TBL.PackagingID, Packaging_TBL.PackagingDate, Packaging_TBL.FromStockID, (SELECT ItemCode FROM Stock_TBL WHERE StockID = Packaging_TBL.FromStockID) AS FromItemCode, Store_TBL.StoreID, Store_TBL.StoreName, Packaging_TBL.FromCurrentQuantityQuantity, Packaging_TBL.FromCurrentBalanceQuantity, Stock_TBL.StockID, Stock_TBL.ItemCode, Packaging_TBL.Quantity
FROM Packaging_TBL INNER JOIN Stock_TBL ON Packaging_TBL.StockID = Stock_TBL.StockID INNER JOIN Store_TBL ON Packaging_TBL.StoreID = Store_TBL.StoreID
WHERE Packaging_TBL.IsTableStatus = 1
ORDER BY Packaging_TBL.PackagingID ASC
```

[image]

Which is working fine.